# phpMyAdmin, is there a something you can add to sql to turn off caching for that query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to test / improve an sql query for speed however caching is not showing me the true speed.

Is there something I can add to sql to turn it off for that query ?

Also, if there isn't how else can I test and find the true speed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a
SQL_NO_CACHE clause to your queries to request that MySQL run the
query rather than return a cached result:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM myTable;
```

Edit:

There is another way of dong this if you have access to configurations

```
setting query_cache_type = 0 or query_cache_type = OFF in MySQL's conf
```

Comment: Note that this only skips the first level query cache, the pages themselves may still be buffered, thus still not indicating the true speed in cache of a completely empty cache.

Comment: @sagi, I'm not sure I understand, will `SQL_NO_CACHE` show me the true picture of the MySql database server which isn't on the webserver ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's:

- [Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html)
- or [Jet Profiler for MySQL](http://www.jetprofiler.com/). (paid)

Comment: It looks like Query Profiler is no longer available.